# html - asp:linkButton dando tp pra aba inicial

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net

estou fazendo um **ERP**, nele tenho várias abas, feitas a partir de bootstrap com tags `<nav>`, numa delas, tenho um link button q ao ser precionado (executa normalmente o **OnClick**) por algum motivo, teleporta para a aba inicial (com classe "**.active**").

tentei manipular o *href*, *postbackurl*, e até usar *JS* pra tentar mudar a aba com a classe "active" para a atual, mas **nada** até ent tem funcionado.

link button em questao :

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn border-0 btn-bg-blue bg-blue" type="button" ID="Buscar_Prod" OnClick="Buscar_Prod_Click" PostBackUrl="#">
           Buscar <i class="bi bi-search ml-1"></i>
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

abas :

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs bg-blue border border-1 border-info" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link bg-blue btn-bg-blue active" id="nav-requesiçao-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-requesiçao" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-requesiçao" aria-selected="true">Requesição</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link bg-blue btn-bg-blue pilula" id="nav-cadastros-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-cadastros" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-cadastros" aria-selected="false">Cadastros</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-requesiçao" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-requesiçao-tab">
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-cadastros" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-cadastros-tab" url="">
      <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs bg-blue border border-1 border-info" id="nav-tab-cadastros" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active bg-blue btn-bg-blue" id="nav-produto-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-produto" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-produto" aria-selected="true">Produtos</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent-cad">
     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-produto" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-produto-tab"></div>
```

Comment: *"tenho um link button q ao ser precionado (executa normalmente o OnClick) por algum motivo, teleporta para a aba inicial"* não está  fazendo post da página e voltando ao estado original? seu controle tem o `runat="server"` e provavelmente está fazendo isso

Comment: o `runat="server"` nao é obrigatorio no asp:linkbutton? n vejo maneiras de tira-lo, n sei como arrumar a partir deste ponto

Comment: a questão não é tirar, a questão que se vai fazer um post, precisa salvar o estado da tab o no reload da página setar novamente

Comment: certo, acho q entendi, vou ir atras e ver se arrumo

Comment: você usa web forms, então precisa por a informação da tua aba numa variável de viewstate (ou server side) para depois recurar isso e setar quando carregar a página :)

Comment: tentei usar algo como:`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var abas = document.querySelectorAll('#nav-tab a[data-toggle="tab"]');
    abas.forEach(function (tab) {
        tab.addEventListener('click', function () {
            localStorage.setItem('abaAtiva', this.getAttribute('href'));
        });
    });
    var abaAtiva = localStorage.getItem('abaAtiva');

    if (abaAtiva) {
        var aba = document.querySelector('a[href="' + abaAtiva + '"]');
        var event = new Event('click');
        aba.dispatchEvent(event);
    } `

Comment: `else {

        var primeiraAba = abas[0];
        var event = new Event('click');
        primeiraAba.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
});` mas n parece estar funcionando como eu esperava